# Mongoose populate sort option

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, populate, mongoose-populate

I am trying to sort a populated document by the populated fields, similar to the example in the mongoose docs:

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-populate

Where Kitten references owner by objectId and a query on Kitten is able to be sorted by the owner name. I've tried numerous variations of the syntax, such as from the answers given in

[How to sort a populated document in find request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16352768/how-to-sort-a-populated-document-in-find-request)

While all of them populate and do not throw any errors, the sort option is not working for me. The one solution I have not tried yet is given here:

[Mongoose, sort based on foreign/populated key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44331221/mongoose-sort-based-on-foreign-populated-key)

But does not use the available functionality of populate from mongoose and feels like a work around. Maybe a pair of fresh eyes could point out my problem.

My models (Semester and SemesterReference):

```
var semesterSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  year: Number,
  season: {
type: String,
enum: ["FALL", "SPRING", "SUMMER"]
  }
});

var semesterReferenceSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  semester: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:"Semester"}
});
```

Result when I query with this code

```
schema.SemesterReference.find().populate({path: "semester", options: {sort: {"year": 1}}}).exec().then(function(result){
console.log(result);
})

[ { _id: 5b2bb2312731613ba06b0e8f,
name: 'ZZZ',
semester:
 { _id: 5b23bd1e0ffe9a29d02ee02c,
   year: 2019,
   season: 'SPRING',
   __v: 0 },
__v: 0 },
{ _id: 5b2bb24b3c19bd1f3c1b0d66,
name: 'AAA',
semester:
 { _id: 5b23bd1e0ffe9a29d02ee011,
   year: 2010,
   season: 'SPRING',
   __v: 0 },
__v: 0 } ]
```

The query returns the same result as if I had not specified sorting by year in options at all. I have tried the same query without quotes around semester or year, which does not work either. Worryingly, changing "year" in the query above to a string that does not match a property of semester (such as asdf) does not throw any errors and the query returns as normal, which seems to indicate that the sort option is being ignored.

I am on version 5.1.6 of mongoose and 3.6.0 of mongodb.

Comment: your query returns year in ascending order... what is the problem here?

Comment: Sort: 1 means sorting in ascending order, my query is returning them in the order they were saved to the database (the incorrect order, which also happens to be descending; 2019 before 2010 is descending order).

Comment: Well you are using latest version of mongoose and mongodb, So do you want to try something different? I mean [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/)

Comment: I'll use lookup for now, from the answer I linked above: sort based on foreign populate key, just to get it to work. But I would still like to figure out why populate is not working for me, as the official docs have a clear example of it working and the research I've done doesn't seem to indicate that the official docs are wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Your first both sources are using an array of refs. As stated in your  [first source](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-populate):

> 'sort' apply to the Author model, not the Book model.

In your example you would need an array of `semesters` in your `semesterReferenceSchema`. Than you can sort the array by year.